# cache remote HTTP asset

Tags: workbox

I wish to use Workbox for caching local as well as remote image assets. Is this currently supported, if so how?

Essentially I'd like to have the following functionality:

```
workboxBuild.injectManifest({
    swSrc: 'app/sw.js',
    swDest: 'build/sw.js',
    globDirectory: 'build',
    globPatterns: [
      '*.css',
      'index.html',
      'app.js',
      'http://remote/image.jpg'
    ],
```

If I manually add the remote HTTP asset to the generated service worker file, that works (see below) but I wish to generate that service worker file without having to manually edit it.

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  {
    "url": "app.css",
    "revision": "f8d6a881fb9d586ef6fd676209e1613b"
  },
  {
    "url": "index.html",
    "revision": "ce6238d5b3c1e4e559349549c9bd30aa"
  },
  {
    "url": "app.js",
    "revision": "4357dbdbcc80dcfbe1f8198ac0313009"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://remote/image.jpg"
  }
]);

} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precaching remote assets isn't supported. That's not likely to change. Workbox needs to take a "snapshot" of each resource prior to deployment, as part of a build process, in order to populate and update its cache, while serving them cache-first. While you could theoretically make an HTTP request for a remote resource as part of your build process, in order to obtain versioning information for it, there's no guarantee that that remote resource won't be re-deployed outside of the deployment cycle of your first-party assets. This could leave you in a situation in which Workbox thinks it has the latest version of `http://example.com/image.jpg`, and never picks up a recent update to it.

The way to [handle third-party](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests), remote assets is to use [runtime routing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing) along with a [caching strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies) that gives you the freshness guarantees you consider appropriate for a particular type of asset. If you want a given asset to be automatically cached as soon as your service worker is installed, you can add in your own `install` handler that will "prime" the runtime cache for you.

This would look something like:

```
// Workbox will continue to precache and keep
// the local assets it knows about up to date.
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([...]);

const cacheName = 'image-cache';

// Make sure that these URLs support CORS!
// Otherwise, the cache.addAll() call will fail,
// and you'll have to explicitly call cache.put()
// for each resource.
const thirdPartyUrls = [
  'https://example.com/image.jpg',
  // Any other URLs.
];

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName)
      .then((cache) => cache.addAll(thirdPartyUrls))
  );
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^https://example.com/'),
  // Use whichever strategy you want.
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName,
    // Use whatever plugins you want.
    plugins: [...],
  }),
);
```